# Click the button to change Vertical screen mode to Horizontal screen mode

Tags: ios, swift

Click the button Vertical screen mode to Horizontal screen mode, chick again  Horizontal screen mode to Vertical screen mode.

How do I achieve this effect?

Comment: you want to rotate at the same view??

Comment: yes, I want this effect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
    -(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

you can use different values as per your orientation change requirements.